# How to load yaml properties which is List of maps of map using Jackson data format?

Tags: java, arrays, properties, configuration, yaml

I have list of product location(key) which starts with 0.0.0.0 which has two values locationname(value) and accessRequired.(value). I want to load this properties properties in the application startup. I am unable to create the hashmap of 0.0.0.0 to hold the locationname and accessRequired. LN and AR are string.
It fails by throwing properties "were left unbound."

To make this simple. This is my ymal file.

```
ProductLocation:
    location:
        '0.0.0.1':
            locationName: 'Building No 3, Aile 41A'
            accessRequired: 'No'
        '0.0.0.2':
            locationName: "Building No 2, Aile 123B'
            accessRequired: 'Yes'
```

Here's what I have in my locationProperties.java file. I am unable to load the above properties with the following code.

```
@Data
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "location")
public static class ProductLocation {
    private String locationName;
    private String accessRequired;
    private HashMap errorcode;
    public void location(HashMap location){
       this.location= location;
    }
    public ProductLocation(){
    }
}
```

I want ProductLocation to contain the values as follows:
I want to have 0.0.0.0 as key which should contain two values which are locationName and accessRequired.

Comment: [YML](https://fdik.org/yml/) is not the same as [YAML](https://yaml.org/spec/1.2/spec.html), your title indicates the first, but your tag the other.

Comment: In Java, you cannot declare a top-level class `static`. Also, you should describe what you mean by „I am unable to load the above properties with the following code“. What happens? How does it fail?

Comment: public static class ProductLocation is not the top-level class. It's an inner class where the other properties configurations are taking place. I need to load the above properties in that class.